# Rails Postgres GROUP all columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, group-by

You must `GROUP BY` all columns you are selecting by in Postgres or it will get mad at you. Is there a simple/clean way to do this other than just listing all the columns?

The best I've come up with is the following (intent is commented):

```
# The purpose of this query is to return a list of `User`s
# ordered by the number of `Account`s they have in descending order.

User.joins(:accounts)
    .group(User.full_column_names)
    .order('COUNT("accounts".*) DESC')
```

From `user.rb`:

```
def self.full_column_names
  column_names.collect {|name| "\"#{table_name}\".\"#{name}\"" }
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you are clear about the usage of `activerecord group method` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group and `postgresql group by clause` http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/? Grouping by all the columns in a table doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm doing an `INNER JOIN` with the `accounts` table to find the Users with the most Accounts so I'm using an aggregate function in my `ORDER` clause.

By default Rails will select all the columns from the AR model, in this case `SELECT "users".* ...` which I want because I'm looking for full `User` objects. Does that make more sense? I could be missing a completely easier solution, this is just the best one I've come up with so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enough time has passed where I have to say that unfortunately there is not a better solution for the specific question I was asking. Maybe Rails 5 will have something and I'll revisit this later. My basic solution in the question works for my usage and could be modified or used in another higher level method without much work to perform the grouping.

This may also be solved in a update to the Postgres adapter.

Answer (score 0):

One way to find the user with the most accounts:

```
user_id, number_of_accounts = Account.group(:user_id).count.max_by{ |key, value| value}
user_with_most_accounts = User.find(user_id)
```

Make it one query with:

```
user_with_most_accounts = User.find(Account.group(:user_id).count.max_by{ |key, value| value}[0])
```

**Note**: This finds only one user even if multiple users have the same number of accounts as the most count.

Comment: I appreciate the alternative searching solution but I was only using the user with the most accounts as an example. What I'm interested in is given that I want to do this in one SQL query involving `JOIN` and aggregate functions, is there a better way than what I have to get around/work with Postgres' need to have all columns in `SELECT` also named in `GROUP BY`.